# URL Variables with/w/o slashes Upload Directories vs Resource URLs

Tags: wordpress, directory, resource-urls

Wordpress 5.0.3

CiviCRM 5.9.0

I'm looking at the help pop-ups compared on two pages. (The text in the black box in the two images)

I've got Path Variables on the Upload Directories page:
[image: Path Variables - Upload Directories Page]

I've got URL Variables on the Resource URLs Page:
[image: URL Variables - Resource URLs page]

They are supposed to be the same variables: [cms.root], [civicrm.root] and [civicrm.files], yet on the former page, the variables have no slashes. On the latter page, they *do* have slashes. I suspect the one *without* slashes is correct, because the Extensions Directory for both uses [civicrm.files]/ext/ and had already been set that way.

Before I make any mistakes, these are the settings I have on Resource URLs *now*:

**CiviCRM Resource URL:** wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/

**Image Upload URL:** wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/

These are what I should probably change them to:

**CiviCRM Resource URL:** [civicrm.root]/

**Image Upload URL:** [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/

Please confirm.

Is it possible this a minor bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not a bug, adding extra '/' won't make any difference. The variables shown Directories and Resource URL forms have same naming conventions however they are rendered in different way for each form.

```
CiviCRM Resource URL: [civicrm.root]/

Image Upload URL: [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/
```

Your Settings looks fine.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you so much. So you're saying that CiviCRM has a routine that checks for both cases and renders accordingly, correct? But still, wouldn't it be more logical if [cms.root] and the other variables were listed identically across the interface for consistency's sake?